# BackgroundWOrker Invalid cross-thread access

Tags: c#, multithreading, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml

I try to add loading datamodel and load items to listbox on another thread because loading of 50 items to listbox takes long time (about 5 seconds).

I have problem with BackgroundWorker it show me error Invalid cross-thread access

His is code of Inbox.xaml

```
    public Inbox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = App.ViewModel;
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        ProgressIndicator progress = new ProgressIndicator
        {
            IsVisible = true,
            IsIndeterminate = true,
            Text = "Načítání"
        };

        SystemTray.SetProgressIndicator(this, progress);
        SystemTray.IsVisible = true;

        BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
        backgroundWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker_DoWork);
        backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted);

        backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        LoadData();
    }

    void backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message);
        }
        else
        {
            SystemTray.IsVisible = false;
        }
    }

    private void LoadData()
    {
        try
        {
            (this.DataContext as MainViewModel).LoadInboxData();
        }
        finally
        {
            TasksListBox.ItemsSource = (this.DataContext as MainViewModel).Tasks;
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What error are you getting? Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: Going to guess it's your `LoadData` as it is accessing the `ItemsSource` of a UI control. You need to invoke the call on the `Dispatcher` I think, though I can't remember exactly.

Comment: You could search for one of the many thousands of questions about this here, and on other sites.  This is a question asked several times a day...Just take a look at the `Related` threads on the side of your screen.

Answer (score 2):

BackgroundWorker.DoWork handler runs on a background non-ui thread. In your example LoadData() method runs on a background non-ui thread and you are setting ListBox's ItemSource property in that method.

You should try and move that code to your BackgroundWorkder.RunWorkerCompleted handler as this handler runs on UI thread.

Your code can be re-written like below to avoid the error:

```
void backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message);
    }
    else
    {
        SystemTray.IsVisible = false;
    TasksListBox.ItemsSource = (this.DataContext as MainViewModel).Tasks;
    }
}

private void LoadData()
{
    (this.DataContext as MainViewModel).LoadInboxData();
}
```

Comment: I have same error when I removeloadinboxdata() row from code and I need to show loading when items are adding to listbox, this is what take long time

Comment: If you are looking to overlay a 'Loading' banner, there are multiple ways you can acheive that

1) Have another control such as a border/textblock/progress bar and then z-order it to appear on top of ListBox and toggle the visibility of that control as needed.

2) User adorner control. Refer to this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/57984/WPF-Loading-Wait-Adorner

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to update the UI from a non-UI thread, so you'll get an exception.

Only the UI thread can perform UI updates, you need to use the `Dispatcher` in order to update UI from a non-UI thread.

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
   // Update UI in here as this part will run on the UI thread.
});
```

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.begininvoke.aspx

Comment: The whole point of using a background worker is so that you aren't manually invoking.  He should simply be updating the UI with the results in the worker completed event instead of the do work event.

Comment: ok it works but I need to show loading when items are adding to listbox, this is what take long time

Comment: @Servy he could indeed! That would be one way of doing it, BUT, if he's got a need to update the UI between long running ops then dispatching the calls is the way to go, unless he creates several background workers and chains them together - messy! A better more "modern" approach would be to simply hand off to a schmancy new async method and let async await with the long ops being forced onto new threads handle all the chaining and heavy lifting.

Comment: @Clint Even with a BGW its still quite simple.  You can simply use the progress reporting mechanisms to update the UI with progress of the long running operation.